# How to specify the return type of a function that returns pointer of one overloaded function using decltype?

Tags: c++, overloading, function-pointers, decltype

How to specify the return type of a function that returns pointer of specific one overloaded function using `decltype`?

Like this:

```
void fun(int a) {
    cout << "void fun(int a) : " << a << endl;
}

void fun(double a) {
    cout << "void fun(double a) : " << a << endl;
}

decltype(?) *getFcnPtr() {
    return fun;
}
```

What if I want `getFcnPtr` to just return the `void fun(int a)` version?

Actually, I'm reading `C++ Primer` and are thinking over the `decltype`.

I know I can use this form:

```
void (*getFcnPtr()) (int a) {
    return fun;
}
```

Or with unoverloaded function, `decltype(FcnName) *getFcnPtr` will do the work, but what to do with `decltype` to specify the return type of `getFcnPtr` if I want to return an overloaded function?

Is it possible for `decltype` to be used this way? Is there a way that can add parameters to help? Something like `decltype(void(int))` or `decltype(fun(int))`, of course these two do not work...

Comment: You might be able to do this with a template and a trailing return type.  Without knowing what parameter the overloaded function is called with I don't know how it would determine which function pointer to return.

Comment: `decltype(fun(int))` You can use `std::declval` for this purpose: `decltype( fun(std::declval<int>()) )`

Comment: For a more general solution, you can wrap the overload set in a function object, and then use [`std::result_of`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e4ae37637fa90e1). In C++14, you can use polymorphic lambdas to do that, in C++11, you'll have to use a custom function object like `struct fun_t { template<typename T> auto operator()(T t) -> decltype(fun(t)) { return fun(t); } };`

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, I just want `getFcnPtr` to return the int version of overloaded functions, so the parameter is known, int. I can't figure out how to use `decltype` together with int type to specify the return type of `getFcnPtr`.

Comment: @dyp Thank you for your comments. I was reading `C++ Primer` and the book said something about `decltype` with normal functions, but nothing with overloaded functions. So I'm thinking that if there is a way using `decltype` together with an overloaded function's name and its parameter to determine the return type of a function, and it seems that there isn't a direct and neat solution.

Comment: @dyp  I tried `decltype(fun(declval<int>())) *getFcnPtr() { return fun ; }`, but g++ report error saying `cannot resolve overloaded function fun based on conversion to type void*`. It looks like `decltype(fun(declval<int>()))*` applies `void*` to function's return type, not a function pointer type?

Comment: `decltype(..)` yields the type of the expression `..` - in this case, it yields the type of the expression `fun(declval<int>())`, which is the *return type* of that function. I do not know of a (general) way to deduce the type of the parameters from an overload set.